# How to put bootstrap code inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web page that i want to use a additional component in it.
that component have a complete set of files including css, html and javascript.
the problem is both my site and the component have bootstrap.css file. there is tag in bootstrap of component file:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after 
{
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

when I add this to my site bootstrap file component works properly but menubar and footer are have some problems when i delete the third line

box-sizing: border-box;

menubar and footer appear well but component would have some troubles.

How can i put this part of bootstrap code inline?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was not very clear and very vague but it seems that you are adding an unnecessary file by including the bootstrap file twice.

If the bootstrap.css you are referring to is the twitter bootstrap then you need to read on how to install twitter bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). 
You should include the bootstrap folder in your root folder and then include the css and js assets from it in your index.html. Or as in the example below take the CSS and JS folders from the Bootstrap folder and place those in your root folder. Some Twitter components have their own css or js and those can be included right below these.

Notice the bootstrap.min.css and the bootstrap.min.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would recommend you read more about how bootstrap works as a library.

Hope this helps.